# Illegal mix of collations (utf8mb4_unicode_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8_general_ci,COERCIBLE) for operation 'like'

Tags: php, mysql

Hi in my sql query i have this error can someone help me how i can fix that?

EDIT: I Added my JavaScript code i think the problem is my JavaScript code because when i use my PHP code directly without sending post method its work as well but with JavaScript i have such problem.

ERROR:

```
Illegal mix of collations (utf8mb4_unicode_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8_general_ci,COERCIBLE) for operation 'like' [1267]
An sql error occurred while fetching this page. Please contact an administrator if this problem persists
```

TABLE

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `core_members` (
  `member_id` mediumint(8) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`member_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

PHP:

```
    @$key = $_POST['key'];

    $result    = $db->sql_query("SELECT member_id, name FROM core_members WHERE name LIKE '%{$key}%' LIMIT 10");
        while ($row = $db->sql_fetchrow($result)) {
         ....
        }

    $db->sql_close();
```

JS:

```
$('#typeahead').keyup(function() {
    if (this.value.length < 4) return;
    var searchField = $('input.typeahead').val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "./_api.php",
        data: 'mod=searchFF&key=%' + searchField,
        success: function(data) {
            $(".tt-suggestions").html(data);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: why is there a `%` in the `data` field of `$.ajax`

Comment: good point, thank you my problem resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need for `%` in the `data` field of `$.ajax` as it can give unknown character on the server side because the url will be treated as encoded